# How many times should I loop to cover all cases of possible sums?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, while-loop

I am trying to solve [this competitive programming problem](https://codeforces.com/contest/1006/problem/C) using python3. The problem asks, given an array of size `n`, split the array into three consecutive, contiguous parts such that the first part has maximum sum and equals the sum of the third part. The elements in the array are positive integers.

[**My approach:**](https://codeforces.com/contest/1006/submission/74979144)

```
inputN = int(input())   
inputString = input()

usableString = stringToList(inputString)

counting = 0
sum1 = usableString[0]
sum3 = usableString[-1]
maxSum1 = 0
countFromLeft = 1
countFromRight = 2

while counting < inputN-1:
    if sum1 > sum3:
        sum3 += usableString[-countFromRight]
        countFromRight += 1
    elif sum3 > sum1:
        sum1 += usableString[countFromLeft]
        countFromLeft += 1
    elif sum1 == sum3:
        maxSum1 = sum1
        sum1 += usableString[countFromLeft]
        countFromLeft += 1
    counting += 1

print(maxSum1)
```

1. We read in the array elements and store them in a list `usableString`.
2. We set two variables `sum1` and `sum3` to the first and last elements of the list respectively.
3. We set a variable to keep track of the maximum sum of the first part of the list.
4. Finally, we set a variable `counting` to 0 which will represent the number of elements we have added from the list into `sum1` or `sum3`.
5. The rest of the logic is in the while loop, which just checks if `sum1` is larger than `sum3` or the other way around and otherwise if they equal. After each iteration we add 1 to counting as an extra element has been included in a part. The while loop should stop when the number of elements used (i.e `counting`) is equal to the number of elements in the array - 1, since we added the first and last elements before entering the loop, which makes (array - 2), however, we still need to loop one additional time to check if `sum1` and `sum3` are equal.

Comment: I've just been writing an answer, but realised that I mis-read something.. what is it you are actually asking?

Comment: I'm confused why my logic doesn't work. Have you read the problem statement? I'm just trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your submitted algorithm, and the problem is your `stringToList` function:

```py
def stringToList(s):
    list=[]
    for elem in s:
        if elem != " ":
            list.append(int(elem))
    return list
```

As far as I can tell, your main algorithm is completely fine, but `stringToList` does one crucial thing incorrectly:

```
>>> stringToList('2 4 6 8 10')
[2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 0]
# should be
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

As it treats each character individually, the two digits of `10` are turned into `1, 0`. A simpler method which performs correctly would be to do the following:

```py
# explanation
>>> input()
'2 4 6 8 10'

>>> input().split(' ')
['2', '4', '6', '8', '10']

>>> map(int, input().split(' ')) # applies the int function to all elements
<map object at 0x...>

>>> list(map(int, input().split(' '))) # converts map object into list
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Sorry it took so long, I ended up making my own algorithm to compare to yours, ran my own tests, and then ran your code with the input to list method I just explained, and figured the only difference was your `stringToList` function. Took a while, but I hope it helps!

Just for the fun, here's my algorithm and turns out it was pretty similar to yours!

```py
array = [1, 3, 2, 1, 4]
n = len(array)
slice = [0, n]
sum = [array[0], 0]
bestSum = 0
while slice[0] < slice[1]-1:
    i = 0 if (sum[0] < sum[1]) else 1
    slice[i] += 1-(2*i)
    sum[i] += array[slice[i]]
    if sum[0] == sum[1]: bestSum = sum[0]
    # print(array[ : slice[0]+1], array[slice[0]+1 : slice[1]], array[slice[1] : ])
print(bestSum)
```

Comment: Epicly ! Thanks @dantechguy.